# Emacs and CNTLM

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to configure Emacs to use CNTLM to work with my company's authenticating proxy. I've followed the steps to configure CNTLM, and I've got the following in my init.el file:

```
(setq url-proxy-services
      '(("http" . "127.0.0.1:3128")
        ("https" . "127.0.0.1:3128")))
```

However, every time I try to perform a package-refresh-contents or a package-list command, I see a prompt at the bottom of Emacs with "Username [for Cntlm for parent]:". What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe that existing question can help with your configuration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783267/how-to-configure-emacs-behind-an-authenticated-http-proxy

Comment: Thanks for that, I used that to setup CNTLM and configure emacs to use it. My issue is that I keep getting prompted for credentials. I know there was an issue with http-url.el that prevented it from caching credentials, but I am using Emacs 24.5, and I verified that file has been fixed.

Comment: Is the problem that Emacs doesn't remember the credentials once you've entered them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Emacs 24.5, but when I upgraded to Emacs 25rc1, it went away. Perhaps the same fix will work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I start Emacs in shell, works with 24+, should also work with 25,

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 emacs
```